# how to make directive with ng-show on the parent to trigger a function on show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a div with ng-show on it. This div is a wrapper for a custom directive that I have created.

HTML

```
<div ng-show="mycondition">
    <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function myDirective() {
    function doSomthing() {...}
}   
angular.module('myapp').directive('myDirective', myDirective);
```

I want the directive to do something, only once the ng-hide class is removed from the wrapper div (in Other words, only "on show") 
How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting! Here's how I'd like to solve this:

I would add `ng-show` like this:

```
ng-show="mycondition && doSomething()"
```

Now, that it will call `doSomething` function whenever your condition meets *i.e.* whenever `ng-show` is truthy.

Cool, let's add this function to `myDirective` and we'll `console.log` inside the function to know whether it is called or not. Like this:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      doSomething: "="
    },
    template: "<h5>inside myDirective!</h5>",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.doSomething = function() {
        console.log("myDirective doing something");
        return true; // Important, this function being a condition of ng-show needs to return true
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Now, lastly, let's call our directive:

```
<div ng-show="mycondition && doSomething()">
  <div my-directive do-something="doSomething"></div>
</div>
```

Find working snippet below. Also, there is a toggle button that toggles `mycondition` to demonstrate it gets called when `true`.

Few things to note,

- Using this way, function needs to return `true` since it is a condition for our `ng-show`
- Function gets called more than once because of the `digest cycle`. But we can get rid of that behavior by having a private variable in `myDirective` scope which gets set to `true` on visit; prevents entering when `true` and sets to `false` when work is done.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.mycondition = true;
  $scope.changeCondition = function() {
    $scope.mycondition = !$scope.mycondition;
  }
});

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      doSomething: "="
    },
    template: "<h5>inside myDirective!</h5>",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.doSomething = function() {
        console.log("myDirective doing something");
        return true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <button ng-click="changeCondition()">toggle</button>
  <div ng-show="mycondition && doSomething()">
    <div my-directive do-something="doSomething"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!

Comment: There is one thing I don't 100% understand:
why do I need to pass the doSomthing to the directive ?

Comment: @Yogev you said `I want the directive to do something` so in order to do that inside directive, we need to pass it to directive.

Answer (score 0):

### AngularJS ng-show Directive

The `ng-show` directive shows the specified HTML element if the expression evaluates to true, otherwise the HTML element is hidden.

---

Here you go. I have provided you an example of a **custom directive** in AngularJS that show a row of sentence if status value equals to true. Hope this helps you. Cheers !

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.status = true;
});

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">

  <div ng-show="status">
    <div my-directive></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```